# Any way to write a dot property in CoffeeScript without parentheses?

Tags: coffeescript

```
Server = require('mongodb').Server
```

That's my `CoffeeScript` now. Any way to drop those `()`?

Comment: Trevor has the solution with destructuring assignment, but you should also check this related [proposal on CoffeeScript issues](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a job for [destructuring assignment](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#destructuring)!

```
{Server} = require 'mongodb'
```

Comment: Unfortunately that link doesn't work. How would you reference Server after this? EDIT: This made it clearer: http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/09/28/destructuring-assignment-in-coffeescript/

Answer (score 5):

```
Server = (require 'mongodb').Server
```

There's really no way to demarcate these two expressions clearly using only whitespace.  I tried:

```
Server = require 'mongodb'
    .Server
```

But the resulting javascript was:

```
var server = require('Server'.Server);
```

Which is obviously wrong and not what you want.

The correct answer here is 'no.'

Parentheses are important; they allow you to isolate and demarcate expressions.  For all of Coffeescript's amazing power to handle some obvious isolations by itself, not every expression can be parsed automagically.  Embrace the parenthetical!

Comment: There is an open ticket for enabling the second case. Vote for https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407 if you're interested.

Answer (score 4):

```
mongo = require 'mongodb'
Server = mongo.Server
```

:)